# date.compare() not working

Tags: java, date, collections

I am trying to compare two dates using `date.compare()`.
But it's always returning `false` as result. This is my code:

*Source Code*

```
public String convertTime(long time)
{
    // Today's Date
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date toDay = new Date(currentTime);
    Date notificationDay = new Date(time);

    Log.i("Date", "Today : "+toDay.toString());
    Log.i("Date", "NfDay : "+notificationDay.toString());

    if (toDay.compareTo(notificationDay) == 0)
    {
        Log.i("Date", "Compare : Yes");
        return "Yes";
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("Date", "Compare : No");
        return "No";
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
08-24 14:04:21.602: I/Date(22277): Compare : No
08-24 14:04:21.632: I/Date(22277): Today : 2015-08-24
08-24 14:04:21.632: I/Date(22277): NfDay : 2015-08-24
08-24 14:04:21.632: I/Date(22277): Compare : No
08-24 14:04:21.642: I/Date(22277): Today : 2015-08-24
08-24 14:04:21.642: I/Date(22277): NfDay : 2015-08-24
08-24 14:04:21.642: I/Date(22277): Compare : No
08-24 14:04:21.662: I/Date(22277): Today : 2015-08-24
08-24 14:04:21.662: I/Date(22277): NfDay : 2015-08-24
08-24 14:04:21.662: I/Date(22277): Compare : No
08-24 14:04:21.692: I/Date(22277): Today : 2015-08-24
08-24 14:04:21.692: I/Date(22277): NfDay : 2015-08-24
08-24 14:04:21.692: I/Date(22277): Compare : No
08-24 14:04:21.712: I/Date(22277): Today : 2015-08-24
08-24 14:04:21.712: I/Date(22277): NfDay : 2015-08-24
08-24 14:04:21.712: I/Date(22277): Compare : No
08-24 14:04:33.022: I/Date(22277): Today : 2015-08-24
08-24 14:04:33.032: I/Date(22277): NfDay : 2015-08-24
08-24 14:04:33.032: I/Date(22277): Compare : No
08-24 14:04:33.042: I/Date(22277): Today : 2015-08-24
08-24 14:04:33.042: I/Date(22277): NfDay : 2015-08-24
08-24 14:04:33.042: I/Date(22277): Compare : No
08-24 14:04:33.042: I/Date(22277): Today : 2015-08-24
08-24 14:04:33.042: I/Date(22277): NfDay : 2015-08-24
08-24 14:04:33.042: I/Date(22277): Compare : No
08-24 14:04:33.052: I/Date(22277): Today : 2015-08-24
08-24 14:04:33.052: I/Date(22277): NfDay : 2015-08-24
08-24 14:04:33.052: I/Date(22277): Compare : No
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by using following code

```
if ((toDay.getYear() == notificationDay.getYear()) && (toDay.getMonth() == notificationDay.getMonth()) && (toDay.getDate() == notificationDay.getDate()))
    {
        Log.i("Date", "Compare : Yes");
        return "Yes";
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("Date", "Compare : No");
        return "No";
    }
```

**Warning:: This is the solution for my requirement. I am not sure it will work for all**

Comment: getDate() returns only the day of month!!! So 2015-8-4 and 2015-9-4 is equals in your case.

Comment: That's why i mentioned there as per my requirement.It's not general solution. we  can use if ((toDay.getYear() == notificationDay.getYear()) && (toDay.getMonth() == notificationDay.getMonth()) && (toDay.getDate() == notificationDay.getDate()))  as general solution

Comment: please add the warning to your answer

Comment: And all of the used methods are deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

The `java.util.Date` has a time part. This part will be different in your code.

Set the timepart to zero and your code should work.

Create a function to convert your date to an absolute Date (time is null):

```
private Date getAbsolutDate(Date time){

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(time);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    return c.getTime();
}
```

and call:

```
if (getAbsoluteDate(toDay).compareTo(getAbsoluteDate(notificationDay)) == 0)
```

Comment: :: Time part... What is it?

Comment: @user5258810 Hour, minute, seconds, milliseconds.

Comment: But i want to check by Date.I mean today or yesterday

Comment: @user5258810 That's why you have to set the hours and so on to zero. if not you compare 2015-08-24 10:02:03.3454 with 2015-08-24 10:02:03.3555 for example

Comment: I written like this and it is working as per my requirement.if (toDay.getDate() == notificationDay.getDate())
  {
   Log.i("Date", "Compare : Yes");
   return "Yes";
  }
  else
  {
   Log.i("Date", "Compare : No");
   return "No";
  }

Comment: @user5258810 getDate() returns only the day of month!!! So 2015-8-4 and 2015-9-4 is equals in your case.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
public static String convertTime()
{
    // Today's Date
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date toDay = new Date(currentTime);
    Date notificationDay = new Date(currentTime);


    if (toDay.getYear()==notificationDay.getYear() && toDay.getDay()==notificationDay.getDay() && toDay.getMonth()==notificationDay.getMonth())
    {
        Log.i("Date", "Compare : Yes");
        return "Yes";
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("Date", "Compare : No");
        return "No";
    }
}
```

Or

```
 if (!toDay.after(notificationDay))
    {
        Log.i("Date", "Compare : Yes");
        return "Yes";
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("Date", "Compare : No");
        return "No";
    }
}
```